# Проблема при освобождении памяти в деструкторе

Tags: классы, исключения, c++11, память, деструктор

Создаю класс для работы с матрицами, но при повторной инициализации объекта в деструкторе падает исключение.

Код:

```
typedef int** DARRAY
typedef unsigned int UINT

class NumCxx
{
private:
    DARRAY dim_array_;      // 2d array     
    UINT columns_;          // array columns
    UINT rows_;             // array columns
    static UINT check;      // amount of class objects
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> massive_;

public:
   NumCxx(std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>> recieved) : massive_(recieved)
    {
        this->massive_ = recieved;
        this->columns_ = massive_.size();
        this->rows_ = massive_[0].size();
        this->dim_array_ = new int* [columns_];


        for (UINT i = 0; i < columns_; ++i)    //copying the recieved array
        {
            this->dim_array_[i] = new int[rows_];

            for (UINT j = 0; j < rows_; ++j)
            {
                this->dim_array_[i][j] = massive_[i][j];
            }
        }
        ++check;
    }

    ~NumCxx() // destructor destoys an array
    {
       for (UINT i = 0; i < this->columns_; i++)
       {
           delete[] this->dim_array_[i];
       }
       delete[] this->dim_array_;
    }
};
```

При создании экземпляра класса все хорошо, однако если сделать вот так:

```
NumCxx a = {{5,6}}; // that's ok
a = {{8, 0}}; // raises an exception
```

то при повторной инициализации деструктор тоже вызывается дважды и пытается уничтожить одну и ту же область памяти `this->dim_array_`. Как быть в такой ситуации?

Comment: Нельзя давать исключениям покинуть деструктор и конструктор до освобождения ресурса (а лучше вообще не давать им вылететь)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы нарушили одно из главных правил - не создали "большую тройку". У вас нет конструктора копирования и присваивания. Их создает компилятор, а созданные им конструктор и оператор присваивания просто выполняют почленное копирование.

Вам нужно создать недостающее, обеспечив *глубокое копирование*, т.е. копирование не указателей, а создание заново с копированием содержимого.

Только объясните мне - если вы можете использовать векторы (т.е. это не учебное задание, в котором от вас требуют выполнения каких-то дидактических ограничений) - то почему не пользоваться только ими? Зачем эти непосредственные выделения в памяти?

Зачем вообще это промежуточное копирование через `massive_`?

Comment: Мне кажется, что стиль C - быстрее (хоть и неудобен) (возможно я не прав, так как с C++ мы только-только переходим на "ты") Если Вам не трудно, не могли бы Вы объяснить, что лучше использовать и почему?)

Comment: Мое мнение - вектора. Получается по сути то же самое по производительности, но зато все вопросы с выделением памяти, освобождением и т.д. решены автоматически. Словом, это как минимум безопаснее :) Что до производительности - это всегда надо только мерять и мерять. Крайне редко удается теоретически предсказать какие-то тонкости правильно :)

Comment: А при использовании векторов имеется ли шанс утечки памяти (при каких-либо обстоятельствах использования)?

Comment: Ну, извратиться можно всегда :) Но при обычной работе - практически нет.